# Confused why a comparison between numbers returns true

Tags: vb.net, if-statement

I am using the following code to check if my health exceeds the max health allowed:

```
    Public Sub healthCheck()

    If Player.CurrentHealth > Player.MaxHealth Then
        MsgBox(Player.CurrentHealth & "&" & Player.MaxHealth)
        Player.CurrentHealth = Player.MaxHealth
        MsgBox(Player.CurrentHealth & "&" & Player.MaxHealth)

    ElseIf (0 > Player.CurrentHealth) Then

        Player.CurrentHealth = 0

    End If

End Sub
```

I added the messageboxes for debugging purposes and they output the following strings:

1st messagebox  =  8&20

2nd messagebox  = 20&20

If the first tells me that

```
currenthealth = 8
```

and

```
maxhealth = 20
```

why does it even enter the if-construction? 
seeing as far as I know, 8 is not higher than 20

Edit:

This only seems to happen below 10 hp! so with 10/20 it doesnt enter the if and just skips the if-construction, however at 9/20 it resets to 20/20 (as if the comparison returned true)

Comment: show the declaration of currenthealth and maxhealth. If they are strings that would explain what you see here.

Comment: Are you sure CurrentHealth and MaxHealth are numbers and not strings?

Comment: Oh dear lord, you are right! I feel so ashamed to have overlooked this..

Comment: Switch `Option Strict On` to prevent your shame in the future  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zcd4xwzs(v=vs.80).aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your health variables are probably strings:

```
MsgBox("8" > "20") // Outputs True
```

Correct with

```
Dim currentHealth As Int32 = Int32.Parse(Player.CurrentHealth)
Dim maxHealth As Int32 = Int32.Parse(Player.MaxHealth)

If currentHealth > maxHealth Then
    MsgBox(currentHealth & "&" & maxHealth)
    Player.CurrentHealth = PLayer.MaxHealth
    currentHealth = maxHealth
    MsgBox(currentHealth & "&" & maxHealth)

ElseIf (0 > currentHealth) Then

    Player.CurrentHealth = 0

End If
```

Answer (score 1):

This question was answered in the comments:

> show the declaration of currenthealth and maxhealth. If they are strings that would explain what you see here. – [Kate Gregory](https://stackoverflow.com/users/203458/kate-gregory)
>
> Oh dear lord, you are right! I feel so ashamed to have overlooked this.. – [Gutanoth](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2060696/gutanoth)